# Use SUM function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, analytics

I have a table in Oracle which contains :

```
 id | month | payment | rev
----------------------------
  A |  1    |  10     |  0
  A |  2    |  20     |  0
  A |  2    |  30     |  1
  A |  3    |  40     |  0
  A |  4    |  50     |  0
  A |  4    |  60     |  1
  A |  4    |  70     |  2
```

I want to calculate the payment column `(SUM(payment))`. For `(id=A month=2)` and `(id=A month=4)`, I just want to take the greatest value from `REV` column. So that the sum is `(10+30+40+70)=150`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This presupposes you don't have more than one value per rev.  If that's not the case, then you probably want a `row_number` analytic instead of `max`.

```
with latest as (
  select
    id, month, payment, rev,
    max (rev) over (partition by id, month) as max_rev
  from table1
)
select sum (payment)
from latest
where rev = max_rev
```

Comment: I prefer the semantics of this over the row_number method: "choose the revision number that is the maximum of `(id, month)` revision numbers". It may also perform better than the row_number method for large data sets as it is easier to store a single max value per `(id,month)` than it is to rank all the possible revision numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can also use below.

```
select id,sum(payment) as value
    from 
    (
    select id,month,max(payment) from table1
    group by id,month
    )
    group by id
```

`Edit`: for checking greatest rev value

```
select id,sum(payment) as value
from (
select id,month,rev,payment ,row_number() over (partition by id,month order by rev desc) as rno     from table1
) where rno=1
group by id
```

Comment: I think the issue with this is that if the max payment is on something other than the latest revision, this will not work.  For example, if revision 1 of month 4 was 100, you would pick that record instead of revision 2

Comment: @Hambone Thanks for bringing this one into notice now i have updated my query please check it.

Comment: Yeah, unless I misunderstood the question I think the second one nailed it

Comment: I prefer the max() method, for reasons outlined on the answer by @Hambone

Answer (score 0):

select sum(payment) from tableName where id='A' and month=2 OR month=4 order by payment asc;

Comment: That's not what the OP wants - they want to sum all months, but for the months with more than one row, only the maximum value.

Comment: I also don't think that compiles...  || in Oracle is concatenate

Comment: Sorry I realize my mistake that in oracle we use OR not ||

Answer (score 0):

Or there's this, if I've understood the requirement right:

```
with demo as (
    select 'A'as id, 1 as month, 10 as payment, 0 as rev from dual
    union all select 'A',2,20,0 from dual
    union all select 'A',2,30,1 from dual
    union all select 'A',3,40,0 from dual
    union all select 'A',4,50,0 from dual
    union all select 'A',4,60,1 from dual
    union all select 'A',4,70,2 from dual
)
select sum(payment) keep (dense_rank last order by rev)
from   demo;
```

You can check the breakdown by including the key columns:

```
with demo as (
    select 'A'as id, 1 as month, 10 as payment, 0 as rev from dual
    union all select 'A',2,20,0 from dual
    union all select 'A',2,30,1 from dual
    union all select 'A',3,40,0 from dual
    union all select 'A',4,50,0 from dual
    union all select 'A',4,60,1 from dual
    union all select 'A',4,70,2 from dual
)
select id, month, max(rev)
     , sum(payment) keep (dense_rank last order by rev)
from   demo
group by id, month;
```